# Method of characteristics for first order PDE question

Tags: partial-differential-equations

why isn't the characteristic curve defined for non-negative values but defined on the whole real line? Is it just an abuse of notation?

We have the initial condition at $s=0$. Wouldn't that imply that in the setting of straightened boundary (half space), $s$ is always non negative? why do we invoke inverse function theorem and say that we can find open subset including $0$ on the whole real line? Shouldn't we state something like $[0, d)$, which is open in the half line?

Comment: Can you provide some more details and context to your question? For instance, is $s$ parameterizing your boundary? Or is it parameterizing the characteristic curves? non-negative values of what are giving you the trouble here?

Comment: @whpowell96 I appreciate your reply. Sorry there was a lack of context. I was referring to Evan's PDE chapter 3. $s$ is parametrizing my characteristic curve corresponding to a certain point $y$ on the boundary. I think I have trouble understanding for example in the page 105 lemma2 when it says "there exists an open interval containing 0 such that..." I'm just wondering how our characteristic line can be defined even when s is negative, which I think is beyond boundary. Like characteristic curve is defined starting at the boundary so it should be either always positive or negative

Comment: Local existence of characteristics is given by existence results for ODEs, which guarantee existence in an open interval about $0$.